# How to add specific actions to ListView when user drags to its start or end (when the curvy blue lines appear)?

Tags: flutter, listview

I'm curious is there an easy way to add such functionality to my Flutter ListViews?
For example, I would like to trigger some animation on another widget when the user drags "over the edge" on the ListView with all of it's items scrolled to the top or bottom, that is when the curvy blue line indicating that we're at the end of the list appears.
It obviously has an event firing up to show those lines anyway.

Comment: check how `RefreshIndicator` provides such functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not hard actually, you can use a custom ScrollController with a listener:

declare it, then in initState put:

```
_myController = ScrollController();
_myController.addListener(_myScrollListener);
```

and the function itself can be something like this:

```
_myScrollListener(){
if (_myController.offset >= _controller.position.maxScrollExtent && !_myController.position.outOfRange) {
  print("List end");
}
if (_myController.offset <= _controller.position.minScrollExtent && !_myController.position.outOfRange) {
  print("List top");
}
```

Use the controller with your ListView, add what you need to the listener.

Answer (score 1):

To add `specific actions` to a `ListView` when the user drags to its start or end in Flutter, you can use the `RefreshIndicator` widget.

The `RefreshIndicator` widget provides a `pull-to-refresh` behavior and can be customized to trigger specific actions when the user pulls the ListView to its start or end.

Here is an example of how you can use the `RefreshIndicator` widget to add specific actions to a ListView:

```
class MyListView extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _MyListViewState createState() => _MyListViewState();
}

class _MyListViewState extends State<MyListView> {
    List<String> _items = List.generate(50, (index) => "Item $index");

    Future<void> _refresh() async {
         // Perform specific action when ListView is pulled to start
         await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
         setState(() {
             _items = List.generate(50, (index) => "Item $index");
         });
     }

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return RefreshIndicator(
             onRefresh: _refresh,
             child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                    title: Text(_items[index]),
                    );
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

[Offical Youtube video for `RefreshIndicator` widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORApMlzwMdM&vl=en)